# Move files of specific extension to individual compressed archives

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to search files by filename extension and pack each found file in a separate archive (one by one) and delete files after compression.
The archive files should be stored in place where files were found.

I expect to identify two parameters for this task: the path to the folder where files should be found and filename extension(s) of these files.

For example:

The path: `d:\folder\`
Extension: `txt`

The found name should be transferred to the 7zip and packing should be started:

```
7z a -mx9 -sdel d:\folder\subfolder1\filename1.txt.7z d:\folder\subfolder1\filename1.txt
```

and after it will be packed and deleted:

```
7z a -mx9 -sdel d:\folder\subfolder2\filename2.txt.7z d:\folder\subfolder2\filename2.txt
```

I've found how to search using the command line:
 
`@If "%1"=="" (Set pathf=D:\folder\) else (Set pathf=%1) 
@If "%2"=="" (Set exmf=*.txt) else (Set exmf=%2)`

but I don't know how to send this information to 7zip in correct format. There is no problem with deleting files, because 7zip has `-sdel` option that solves the problem.

Comment: This is not a coding request site, saying you couldn't find something similar shows only that your not willing to adapt your solution from multiple answers. It's sometimes possible that your exact question hasn't been asked before, but the parts you need for your particular task will have been, _(Accepting arguments, using 7-Zip, deleting files)_. You need to try harder and at least incorporate into your question, code which tries to perform all the tasks you require of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've set your variables using the commands from your question, just add this line:

```
for /r "%pathf%" %%f in ("%exmf%") do 7z a -mx9 -sdel "%%f.7z" "%%f"
```